# Почему не срабатывает событие?

Tags: c#, http

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var url = @"https://anwap.film/films/load/MDE=/1/19161";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "VLC/2.2.8 LibVLC/2.2.8");
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Total: {e.TotalBytesToReceive}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {e.BytesReceived}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Percent: {e.ProgressPercentage}");

        };
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), $@"c:\output.mp4");
    }
}
```

1. Почему не срабатывает событие?
2. Почему консолька закрывается сразу же, не дожидаясь завершения скачивания файла?

Comment: Потому что вы запускаете асинхронно, но не дожитаетесь окончания загрузки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените строку

```
webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), $@"c:\output.mp4");
```

на

```
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), $@"c:\output.mp4");
```

Comment: Угу. Разобрался. + добавить в конце Console.ReadKey();

Comment: Ну да, пока я писал ответ - и вы разобрались.